# Different USB device behaviour on two machines

Tags: windows, usb

I have DVR which connected to PC via mini-USB cable. When I connect it to my home PC, DVR turns on, Windows makes the "recognize device" sound and then DVR turns off. If I connect DVR to my laptop, DVR turns on, windows recognize it, and then i can read videos from DVR. What is wrong with my PC, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall drivers?

Comment: what versions of OS are your PC and laptop running ?

Comment: Both PC run Windows 7 (Pro). What driver should i reinstall? USB Host controller?

Comment: @ko4evneg: When the DVR is connected to the PC, does it show up in Device Manager (even as an unrecognised device)?

Comment: No. It's not shown.

Comment: I found that DVR works well, when i boot from another windows in the same computer. But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Does the DVR have external power or is it powered via USB?  If via USB it might not be getting enough power.

Try the BIOS settings for the USB ports too, make sure they are not set to "1.1" or "Compatible" and if you have the option, check the interrupts and I/O for the USB ports.  Legacy of IBM PC sometimes rears its ugly head even today.

Also are you using the same cable?  It could be something simple like that.

Comment: @OP An easier first step would be to try connecting it through a powered USB hub each computer (assuming your DVR is USB-powered).  If you get different results, it's not a power issue.  If you get the same results...it looks like Tom V solved your problem.  :)

Comment: It's not that problem. As I mentioned earlier i had run virtual machine in problem PC, and within this machine DVR works fine. So it's software problem, not hardware. I don't know how can i track what it cause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you say you were running a virtual machine within the problem PC and that the virtual machine worked while the PC didn't?  If this is the case, then that means you have a pass through set up for USB in order for the virtual machine to use the device.  You need to disable this somehow.  Can you be more specific regarding the type of VM you used?

Comment: Sorry, i missed some details. Actually i run clear system, using boot from VHD image at the same machine

Comment: Can you give me further details?  In an earlier comment you have "As I mentioned earlier i had run virtual machine in problem PC, and within this machine DVR works fine."  Do you mean it worked as part of the virtual machine, but does not when you natively boot into an OS?

Comment: I used VHD boot. It is virtual hard drive with clean windows on it. It is equal installing clean windows to another partition. So to be clear: when i boot to problem system DVR not work. When i boot to another system in this computer DVR works.

Comment: I would verify that all the drivers are the same, including the chipset drivers.  Something must be corrupt with your USB drivers, your chipset drivers, or your Windows installation in order for this problem to be occuring.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of suggestions I can make.

First, find the drivers for the DVR online and install them on your PC. (Manufacturers always list their drivers online for situations like these.) Chances are, your PC is unable to read the 'automatic plug-n-play' drivers from your DVR. Some PCs display this problem and the solution is to install the drivers on these manually.

Second, try plugging into several different USB ports. Some USB ports on your PC may be faulty while others may be working perfectly.

Good luck!